# How to Produce All of the Greek Diacritics Seen Here?

Tags: greek, diacritical-mark

I am trying to replicate (as closely as possible) the following Greek (with diacritics):

[image]

I am using the `\textgreek` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\textgreek{\textbf{\emph{onpwe tan Dios {armonian} jnatwn parexiasi bonlau}}}
\end{document}
```

which produces (with the diacritics I can handle):

[image]

QUESTION: How may the code be modified in order to handle the missing diacritics; also, how may I produce an alpha (instead of an `a') where needed? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're fine with using `babel`, then you can type the Greek directly:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\foreignlanguage{polytonicgreek}{\emph{οὔπωε τὰν Διὸς ἁρμονίαν θνατῶν παρεξίασι βουλαί}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Quote from Prometheus Bound in polytonic Greek]

As for the a's, those *are* alphas. I believe they just look different because of the font (same with the epsilons and thetas).

PS: I see online sources (e.g., [this one](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0009%3Acard%3D545)) write "οὔποτε" instead of "οὔπωε"; is this a typo in your original source?

Comment: +1 Thank you for this answer. I am not very familiar with babel, so I ask: in `\usepackage{babel}`, there is no language specified. Do I not need to specify something like `[greek]` or `[polytonicgreek]`? Thanks again.

Comment: And thanks for pointing out your "typo" observation.

Comment: @DDS You don't need to specify Greek as a package option in your case. You *can* specify it if you wish, but then you'd also need to specify English as the main language. Otherwise, `babel` will treat the entire document as "Greek" (you can try this out by specifying `[greek]` and then adding some English text to the MWE). Plus, I'm assuming that the Greek is just a one-off quote and doesn't make up a significant part of your document.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer; and for the comment..

Comment: @bonk This is the correct approach to handling Greek text. Better unless writing for a journal that does not allow LuaTeX or XeLaTeX to use LuaTeX and only introduce babel, for longer texts. With the newer engines there is no need for any packages.

Answer (score 4):

You get the *spiritus lenis* with `>`, the *spiritus asper* with `<`, the acute, grave and circumflex accents respectively with `` ' ` \~ `` (the last one can be just `~` but only if not in the argument to a command, like in your case).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[main=english,polutonikogreek]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\foreignlanguage{greek}{%
  o>'upwe tan Di'os <armon'ian jnat\~wn parex'iasi boula'i%
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `u` and not `n`.

Answer (score 0):

From your MWE, I assume that you use 8-bit LaTeX (pdflatex).

The simplest way for polytonic (multi-accented) Greek is IMO the "textalpha" package that comes with the greek-fontenc bundle (on CTAN and TeXLive).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[keep-semicolon]{textalpha}
\begin{document}
Single characters ans short words can simply be
put in as literal Unicode characters: ἐρῶν.

Longer passages should be wrapped \ensuregreek{ἐρῶν άπῆλθες εὐθύς;} or, for better hyphenation, be marked up with the correct "Babel" language.

Then you can also use accent macros and the Latin
transliteration, e.g., \ensuregreek{\~w, \'h, \'"i, \`>a|, \'ai}.

\end{document}
```

Greek with 8-bit TeX is tricky, be prepared for surprises or read the documentation.

Unfortunately, there is no list of all accent macros.
The file [char-list.tex](https://mirrors.ctan.org/language/greek/greek-fontenc/char-list.tex) tests all supported characters from the "Greek and Coptic" and "Greek Extended" Unicode blocks with various input variants and may serve as refernce.